# Is it possible to do A/B or Multivariate testing in Sitecore XM scaled topology?

Tags: content-testing

Can we use Sitecore A/B and multivariate testing in XM scaled topology? If no, what can be the possible options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A/B and multivariate testing in XM-scaled topology. Sitecore Experience Manager (CMS-only mode) allows you to run Sitecore XP without enabling the Experience Database (xDB) or purchasing xDB licenses.

**Experience Manager can run the following features with limitations:**

- Personalization – You can implement some in-session personalization rules, such as ones based on device detection, to provide personalized content to your contacts. You cannot, however, implement any personalization rules that are based on historical data, such as outcomes or past goals triggered.
- Device detection – The device database exists on the instance and it is possible to use the API for custom development.
- IP Geolocation detection – The IP Geolocation service can be enabled using the API, but personalization rules are not available.
- Sitecore Forms – runs without any analytics functionality.

**Experience Manager can not run the following features:**

- Experience Explorer
- Campaign Creator
- Commerce Connect
- Content testing
- Email Experience Manager
- Experience Analytics
- Experience Profile
- List Manager
- Path Analyzer
- Segmentation
- Federated Experience Manager
- Marketing Automation

You need to use the Sitecore XP topology.

Reference for more details:

https://www.codehousegroup.com/insights/how-to-use-ab-and-multivariate-testing-in-sitecore

https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/setting-up-sitecore-personalization-second-step

Hope it helps!